# How to dump jvm memery in docker swarm mode?

Tags: docker, jvm, docker-swarm

My springcloud applications are running in docker swarm mode, and recently I found that the memory usage is not in the normal level. I want to use some tools like jmap or something else to dump the heap so that I can change the params of jvm and solve the problem.

I have tried to use some tools like arthas ,but it failed because of the pid 1 problem. We can not attach to a process which id is 1-5.

How can I know the heap usage ( eden、survivor etc) ？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I think is to get into container's shell and install necessary tools right there. Use this on a node with the application container to start interactive session:

```
docker exec -u root -it <container_name> sh
```

Stop the container after you finished to recreate it and thus clean up.

If at some point you need to extract a file from container (e.g. dump) use `docker cp` from another console on the node:

```
docker cp <container_name>:<path_in_container> <local_path>
```

Comment: But the pid is 1 means that it can not be attach , it is the LinuxThread.

Comment: No, process ID 1 belongs to the first process started. On desktop Linux this is `systemd` but in Docker PID 1 is  your application (if the container runs in isolated `proc` space which is so by default). I don't see why it isn't possible to attach to PID 1 when it is your application. @JacobChan